# azure cloud publish docker greyed out

Tags: python, azure, function

I'm new to Azure, I have used AWS for many years. I want to create a Azure function using a docker greyed out no matter how a vary the options. image (ideally pub to docker hub). when I try to manually create the function in the portal (new account) the publish option has docker . I have setup billing.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option magically stopped being greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as of sep 2021 Azure is unable to do Docker Functions with the consumption service plan kind of sucks but I'll see where that puts me.